# Knockout JS foreach looping through array of objects

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a observableArray:

```
self.stats = ko.observableArray([
        {"DFTD" : new Stat("Defensive TD", "DFTD",0,20,0,self.playerGroups[1])},
        {"GL" : new Stat("Games Lost", "GL",0,16,0,self.playerGroups[2])},
        {"FGA" : new Stat("Field Goals ATT", "FGA",0,100,0,self.playerGroups[0])},

    ]);
```

and i am trying to loop around it with a foreach and then print out the Stat objects name property which is the first element in that object.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: stats" id="stat-sliders">
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: stats.Stat().name"></span></td>
            <!--/*<td class="statsListItem">
                    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Im not sure if im doing it right. I am a beginner with knockout and wondering if anyone can help?

Answer (score 3):

The fiddle below creates an array of football stats, which contains a key field and a stat field. You could use the key field for quicker access if you like. If you want an object where you have the property be the key, that would allow for the quickest indexing, though its not an array then.

See if this is what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/CgFjJ/

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to call back into `stats`. Notice that the `span` binds to the property of the model that is inside the array.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: stats" id="stat-sliders">
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
            <!--/*<td class="statsListItem">
                    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Also, I don't think Knockout works well with keyed arrays like that.

Comment: what is the best way to setup the array then? i want to make it so the key is a text value.

Comment: it should just be a property of `Stat`.

Comment: So what im trying to do is take another array and iterate throuhh it for each key in that other array i want to look up in the array above teh value of that specific key from the other array without having to iterate through teh whole array and check the property value for every entry to make sure it matches the key in the other array. Thoughts?